# How to make textbox display difference in table size

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have two tables, **A** and **B**. I always know that table **B** is going to consist of a smaller number of entries. For the sake of argument, lets say that table **A** contains 5 entries and table **B** contains 2 entries. I always know that table **B** is going to consist of a smaller number of entries.

I want to have a form display the difference in the size of the two tables within a textbox. So in this case it should display a value of 3.

I have never used VBA before, and I am a bit confused on how to actually get the textbox to display this. I tried setting up a "before update" script, but I have had no luck. If someone could help me out, that be great.

Comment: SizeDiff = Dcount("[KeyFieldNameHere]","TableNameHere") - Dcount("[KeyFieldNameHere]","TableNameHere"))

Comment: @RetiredGeek Thank you, but how do i get the textbox to display this value?

Comment: @Stan You no need `VBA` for this. Use @RetiredGeek formula to textbox control source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a form, use below expression to textbox control source.

```
=DCount("*","[Table1]")-DCount("*","[Table2]")
```

[image]